# Convergence of sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n+1})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulties showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n+1})}$ converges to $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ for $|x|<1$.

It's easy to see that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

by using the geometric series. It seems I can't use that fact because clearly $(1-x^n)(1-x^{n+1})\neq 1-x$. Also, decomposing the fractions into several fractions with simple denominators seems too convoluted because I would have to work with cyclotomic polynomials. Is this the way to go or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $.

Observe that for any $ x\in\mathbb{R} $, and $ k\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, we have : $$ \frac{x^{k}}{\left(1-x^{k}\right)\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{k}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{k+1}}\right) $$

Thus : \begin{aligned} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{x^{k}}{\left(1-x^{k}\right)\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)}}&=\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{k}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{k+1}}\right)}\\ &=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-x^{n}}\right) \end{aligned}

Now when $ n $ goes to $ +\infty $ :

If $ \left|x\right|<1 $, our series converges to $ \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-1\right)=\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}} $.

If $ \left|x\right|>1 $, our series does also converge, but this time to $ \frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}} $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^n,$ then
$$ \frac{x^n}{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n+1})} = \frac{u}{(1-u)(1-xu)} = \frac{1}{1-x} \left( \frac{u}{1-u} - \frac{xu}{1-xu}\right) = \frac{1}{1-x} \left( \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}}\right).$$

Now the series is telescoping.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$1-x^n-(1-x^{n+1})=x^n(x-1)$$

$$(x-1)\cdot\dfrac{x^n}{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n+1})}=f(n+1)-f(n)$$ where $f(m)=\dfrac1{1-x^m}$

For partial sum  using Telescoping Series,
$$(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{x^n}{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n+1})}=\sum_{n=1}^m(f(n+1)-f(n))=f(m+1)-f(1)$$

Now set $m\to\infty$